# Opencart 3.x category id in product page

Tags: twig, opencart, opencart-3

I'm using opencart 3.0.2.0

I'm trying to get category id in the product page.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Can you elaborate the question, what do you actually want?

Comment: I want to add a button on the product page, based on the product category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to get category id in the product page

Open product.php file from catalog/controller/product

and search for

```
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
```

replace it with

```
$product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
        $query_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);

        $categories = array();

        foreach ($query_categories as $cat) {
            $ocb_category = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($cat['category_id']);

            $category_info['category_id'] = $ocb_category['category_id'];
            $category_info['name'] = $ocb_category['name'];
            $data['categories'][] = $category_info; 
        }
```

open your product.twig file

paste this code in it

```
{% if (categories) %} 
    {% for category in categories %} 
        {% if category.category_id %} 
           <a>{{category.name}}:{{category.category_id}}<a><br>
        {% endif %} 
    {% endfor %} 
{% endif %}
```

Result: Category_name:Category_id (i.e. Electronics:223)

**Note: If the product is in multiple categories it will print all the categories with their ids**

Hope this might help you